# how to apply customization migration scripts in flyway

Tags: flyway

i am using fly way to migrate the core product from older version to newer version. This work wonderful.

But I have a case, where we want to migrate customization specific script on top of Core product version. As you know, each client may have different customization.

For example.

Say core version is 2.2.1. 
Customization 1 version is 1.0 
Customization 2 version is 1.0

Now i would like to apply flyway similar to this
V__description.sql

For the above example, it would be like
V2.2.1_1_1.0__ThisIsCusotmization1.sql
V2.2.1_2_1.0__ThisIsCusotmization2.sql

This is little cumbersome for us.

Is this possible to use alphabets/alpha-numeric in version names like below?

V2.2.1_CUST1_1.0__ThisIsCusotmization1.sql
V2.2.1_CUST2_1.0__ThisIsCusotmization2.sql
V2.2.1_RC1_1.0__ThisIsCusotmization1.sql

Note: Moreover, I could nt see any significance of using prefix (V) here. Please let me know its purpose. Also please let me know whehter we can use more than one prefix like one for core product and other for customization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sound of your question, you probably should go for two Flyway instances. One for core, managing only these changes and another one for the customization.

Each could then be configured with a different location to resolve the migrations from.

Comment: So you mean we have to maintain two different schema table? one for Core (schema_core_version) and other for Customization (schema_Cust_version)?

Comment: Yes, I believe this could be a good solution for your situation.